# code checks one checkbox or the other, but not both

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

So basically, I have a function that is ran when a post is created on wordpress. I've modified this function by adding the following code.

```
$episodeID = $_POST['item_meta'][137];
$episodeVersion = $_POST['item_meta'][357];



if ($episodeVersion == "Subbed") { 
    $value = array("Subbed");

    update_field('field_48', $value, $episodeID);

} 
else if ($episodeVersion == "Dubbed") { 
    $value = array("Dubbed");

    update_field('field_48', $value, $episodeID);



}
```

This code basically says, if the value of a field in that post is "Subbed" then update another checkbox field by checking the "Subbed" checkbox. If it's "Dubbed" then update the checkbox field by selecting the "Dubbed" checkbox.

This works perfectly fine, however there is no time when both of these checkboxes are checked. If I add a post with the Dubbed, it'll check dubbed, then if I add a post with Subbed, it'll uncheck dubbed and check subbed.

So basically, how can I make it so it doesn't actually uncheck whatever has already been checked. So what should I use to check to see if the checkbox is unchecked or checked? Some type of boolean true / false?

Comment: If update_field just sets a check on the field then you can just take away the "else" keyword so that if Subbed it'll check subbed and then check if Dubbed then check dubbed. As you have it the two are mutually exclusive so only one or other whereas when you have both if's then both can occur at the same time.

Comment: i guess that logically makes sense. Only if the if condition could be true in one post which doesn't happen. Meaning one post can only either have Subbed or Dubbed. But the field's value that it's updating can have Subbed and Dubbed checked. So if there was a post that was submitted with Subbed value, and then another that was submitted as "Dubbed" then both of the checkboxes should be checked on the other post. But that doesn't happen, only one or the other is checked.

Comment: Need more code then, like your html and how update_field is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to manipulate some of the code and get it to work eventually.

All I had to do was check if the Subbed checkbox was already checked when executing the dubbed  if statement, and vice versa.

Here is the updated code

```
$episodeID = $_POST['item_meta'][137];
$episodeVersion = $_POST['item_meta'][357];



if ($episodeVersion == "Subbed" && !(get_field('episode_sdversion') && in_array('Subbed', get_field('episode_sdversion', $episodeID))) ) { 
    if (get_field('episode_sdversion') && in_array( 'Dubbed', get_field('episode_sdversion'))) {    
        $value = array("Subbed", "Dubbed");         
    } else {
        $value = array("Subbed");
    }       

    update_field('field_48', $value, $episodeID);

} 
if ($episodeVersion == "Dubbed" && !(get_field('episode_sdversion') && in_array('Dubbed', get_field('episode_sdversion', $episodeID))) ) { 

    if (get_field('episode_sdversion') && in_array( 'Subbed', get_field('episode_sdversion'))) {    
        $value = array("Subbed", "Dubbed");         
    } else {
        $value = array("Dubbed");
    }

    update_field('field_48', $value, $episodeID);



}
```